# Import classes from composer library

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having trouble importing classes from an installed composer library. I have verified the files are under `vendor/defuse/php-encryption` but I get this error when running the code in the PHP CLI:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Defuse\Key' not found in
>   /home/appleking/decryptor/index.php:19

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Defuse\Crypto as Crypto;
use Defuse\Key as Key;

class SafeCrypt {

    protected $encryptkey = 'REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY';

    public function __construct()
  {
        $this->loadedKey = $this->loadEncryptionKeyFromConfig();
    }

    protected function loadEncryptionKeyFromConfig(){
        $keyAscii = $this->encryptkey;
        return Key::loadFromAsciiSafeString($keyAscii);
    }

    public function encryptData($data){
        $ciphertext = Crypto::encrypt($data, $this->loadedKey);
        return $ciphertext;
    }

    public function decryptData($data){
        return Crypto::decrypt($data, $this->loadedKey);
    }

}

$safeCrypt = new SafeCrypt();

print($safeCrypt->decryptData('REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the `Crypto` and `Key` classes are under the namespace

```
namespace Defuse\Crypto;
```

so to import the classes under that namespace, it needs to be:

```
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use Defuse\Crypto\Key;
```

The pattern is:

```
use The\Full\Namespace\AndTheClassName;
```

---

**Side note:**

Regarding the `as` keyword you're using. That's only needed if you want to create an alias of the class.

For example, you want to use two different classes called `Foo` under different namespaces, this would fail:

```
use Namespace1\Foo;
use Namespace2\Foo;
```

PHP wouldn't have a clue which `Foo` you mean if you tried using it in your code.

To solve that, you can make an alias:

```
use Namespace1\Foo as Foo1;
use Namespace2\Foo as Foo2;
```

Now you can use `Foo1` and `Foo2` in your code while PHP knows which you mean.

So there's no need to have `use Namespace1\Foo as Foo;` if that's the only `Foo` in your code/namespace.